# Moving Markers - Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

i'm making a flight tracker for Microsoft FSX and I've made something were the LAT and LNG comes from a socket.io port and then calls a function to add the marker with the imported lat and lng will add or move the marker the code is at http://echoalliance.tk:3000/code.zip and the page is http://echoalliance.tk:3000/Tracker I ask for help on this lots of times

When i send the lat and lng the marker shows up and does not move and it need to move real time

Comment: What is the issue you're having? Please post snippets of your code here and not the .zip archive.

Comment: i can't get the marker to move, i can't with the why i have wrote the code